# Adding F# projects as references to C++/CLI projects not possible?

Tags: f#, c++-cli

I am trying to add an F# project as a reference to a C++/CLI project in VS 2015 but I always get the error that the reference cannot be added because it is incompatible.

Is using F# projects impossible for C++/CLI? Do I have to compile them and add the DLLs to circumvent this?

@Downvoters: Please explain why so I can improve things in the future. Thanks.

Comment: It is not happy about adding a project reference.  Surely because it doesn't know beans about an .fsproj file.  Adding a file reference (use the Browse button) works just fine.  Inconvenient, but not a show-stopper.

Comment: Are you sure the F# project isn't referencing a higher framework version than the C++/CLI project? If it's not the case, you can use Hans' suggestion, but remember to add a build dependency to the C++/CLI project, so it gets recompiled when the F# project changes.

Comment: I even set the framework of the F# project as low as .net 4.0 and it didn't work (The C++/CLI project compiles with VS 2013 because of third-party native dependencies). I guess I am going with using a file reference and a build dependency.